# Sending email in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

my wordpress site email goes to Spam with php function,some site offer me using `wp-mail-smtp` plugin will repair my problem, but it doesn't help me!

when I use php `mail()` function my emails goes to spam
and when i use SMTP, i have an error like this: `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)`

i use this settings for smtp (in `wp-mail-smtp` plugin):

`From Email: noreply@mydoamin.com
SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 465
Encryption: Use SSL encryption
Authentication: Yes: Use SMTP authentication
Username: myEmail@gmail.com
Password: mypassword`

this settings give me an error!
note: i use captcha code and my server tell me port 465 is Open!

how can I send email in my wordpress site ?

Comment: BlueHost blocks all outgoing SMTP requests, as do some other hosts. Please try to get this confirmed via your host. Also check this http://aldrin.aquisap.info/2012/08/26/wp-mail-smtp-in-wordpress-hosted-by-bluehost/ (if your hosting is from Bluehost) else contact your hosting provider.

Comment: you might want to look into a free 3rd party mail api like that provided by http://mandrill.com/ (from the guys who run mailchimp). It has some really nice features like templating, officialising your emails from a domain etc

Comment: dear Neo: i do this! but it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

A connection timed out means that the connection isn't going through. This could be your host, since I just checked your settings - they look OK!

I would look into contacting your host with this. For all I know, that's all you can do, unless you are going to use a 3rd party mail API.

Comment: i contact to my host admin but it tell me everybody can use smtp, and now i never use any 3rd party mail API

Answer (score 0):

A connection timeout means your host is dropping your outbound request to Gmail. You'll need to [send your Gmail out on the HTTPS port](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-gmail-extension/) using a WordPress plugin called Postman SMTP.